# Test a variable's Existence

Tags: .net, vb.net

I actually tried to check whether a `variable` defined in the program or not.
I had done it by using the `exception handling` technique like below,

```
private sub IsTestVarDefined() as boolean
  try
   dim xDummy = AnObject.TestVar  'Where AnObject is using the type Object
   return true
  catch
   return false
  end try
end sub
```

Is there any simple solutions available to achieve this.? or is this fine to implement.?

If i am programming with javascript, then i would have done like this,

```
if(TypeOf Testvar === "undefined") { ... }
```

I have been searching for the methodology which is very similar to the above, in vb.net.

**A sample picture of my case:**

```
Public Class Class1
 public Dim xVar as integer = 0
End Class 

Public Class Class2
 public Dim xAnotherVar as integer = 0
End Class 

Public Class SomeOtherClass
 Dim xObj as Object  = New Class2
 'Now i want to check whether the xObj is having xVar or Not?
End Class
```

***Additional Notes:***

@Damien_The_Unbeliever solution returning Nothing eventhough the casted object having that member.

```
'Evaluated by using the above case i given
 ?xObj.GetType().GetProperty("xAnotherVar")
 Nothing
```

Comment: Do you mean "does AnObject.TestVar have a value" or "does AnObject have a variable called TestVar"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
Return AnObject.GetType().GetProperty("TestVar") IsNot Nothing
```

Comment: Glad to know about a new concept, But this solution would not suit my requirement. Because i am casting the particular object into the Type OBJECT. Say, Class1 is having variable xVar. But Class2 doesn't. I am creating instance for both the classes and casting them into a common type OBJECT. Now how can i find out the casted objects are having the variable xVar or not.?

Comment: Whenever i am using your fix on those casted objects, It is simply returning Nothing even though it is having that variable.

Comment: @RajaPrabhuOfficial: It seems that you have declared `TestVar` as a mere field, not as a property. Therefore, try and use [`GetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee.aspx) rather than [`GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx).

Comment: @RajaPrabhuOfficial - you could even just use [`GetMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdtchs6z.aspx) if you just want to check that the object has *something* called `TestVar`. I'd assumed it was a property.

Comment: I just preferred the `GetMember` function as stated by you. And it is doing its job perfectly fine. Plus One! If you add details to your  answer related to `GetMember`/`GetField` then it would be helpful for the future referrers.

Comment: But this is assuming the variable is a property/member of AnObject, isn't it...but what if the variable is not part of any object...like `dim myVar`?

Answer (score 0):

Just 3 lines of code can do the job:

```
private sub IsTestVarDefined() as boolean
   return Not AnObject Is Nothing
end sub
```

and if you want to test if variable is defined (but variable has to be reference type)

```
private sub IsTestVarDefined() as boolean 
   if AnObject Is Nothing OrElse AnObject.TestVar is Nothing
      return false
   else
       return true
end sub
```

Comment: I think that was not the question. The question was: Does the property *inside* the object exist or not?

Comment: VB.Net treats `Object` the same way as C#'s `dynamic` - so they're actually testing for the existence of the property I think.

Comment: If you're checking against 'nothing' you're checking if it has a value/instance assigned or not. We want to know if the object has the property declared. For this you need to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more appropriate to promote this to a property and define it in an Interface, than trying to use reflection? Then you can cast your object into the interface type and deal with it in a strongly typed manner?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim horsie As Object = New Horse()
    Dim cart As Object = New Cart()

    Dim ihorsie As IMyVal = TryCast(horsie, IMyVal)
    Dim icart As IMyVal = TryCast(cart, IMyVal)

    Console.WriteLine("horsie has myVal (Interface): " & (ihorsie IsNot Nothing))
    'true
    Console.WriteLine("cart has myVal (Interface): " & (icart IsNot Nothing))
    'false
End Sub

Public Interface IMyVal
    Property myVal() As Integer
End Interface

Public Class Horse
    Implements IMyVal
    Public Property myVal() As Integer Implements IMyVal.myVal
        Get
            Return m_myVal
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_myVal = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_myVal As Integer
End Class

Public Class Cart

End Class
```

If you must go with using it as a variable and using reflection to find it, Damien_The_Unbeliever's response (and subsequent comment about GetField) is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise this was a VB question, I'll update the code to VB